# How do you customize the extra buttons on a *Microsoft Classic Intellimouse* in Windows 10?

Tags: intellimouse

*Microsoft* states that their *Classic Intellimouse* supports 3 customizable buttons in Windows 7/8/10, except for Windows 10 S. I keep hitting the side buttons and want to disable them.

The default mouse control settings do not offer this. Searching around, I saw the *IntelliPoint* software should be able to do it.

*Intellipoint* seems to be no longer supported as the official download says it is compatible up to Windows 7. But I tried version 8.2 anyway and saw that it replaces the stock mouse control panel applet but complains that it can't find a Microsoft mouse. The mouse continues to work, I just can't configure it with the Intellipoint applet. Since the driver is from 2011 I thought I should keep digging.

No other mouse or trackpad drivers are installed on this machine, it's a tower that I built myself using a retail copy of Windows 10. I've tried other USB ports. My other machine here is a laptop that does have a trackpad, so I have not tried it there yet.

I can't find a technical or user manual for the product to direct me where to make the settings changes. Hidden in the very Apple inspired box was a multipage booklet that had nothing but the warranty and regulatory information.

Comment: Naming things is hard. In this case Classic is part of the new name, like Classic Coke even though it is not exactly the same as the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The download page referenced originally is gone. [Mouse and keyboard Center Download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2) has the current version of the **Mouse and Keyboard Center**.

<s>I found this Microsoft specifications page about the Classic Intellimouse. It has a download section that points to the *Mouse and Keyboard Center 11*.</s>

I installed that and it is an application as well as an additional tab with a link to the application in the mouse settings of Windows 10.

From there it was easy to set up the buttons the way I want.

Looking further there is a *Mouse and Keyboard Center 12* release, but I'll stick with the one the linked paged offered as it seems the biggest change is additional devices.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I had the very same problem (except i wanted to use those extra buttons). This works perfectly. I'll be hanging on to that download; never know when it will disappear in the regular rearranging of MS website.